# hook_theme() in a custom file of my module

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm facing an issue for a few hours now. I created a new module that must render an admin page with some settings and another one with analytics data. The second one must use a custom template file that I created for the occasion.

I added a `hook_theme()` in my **.module** file and everything worked fine for a while.

When refactoring my code I wanted to move the `hook_theme()` in a **subfile.inc** of my module. Even though I cleared the caches, I always get the issue *Theme hook "my_custom_template" not found.*.

After moving back the hook in the **.module** file everything work again.

Are they some hooks that must be in the **.module** file only. As the `hook_install()` and `hook_uninstall()` must be in the **.install** file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, you mean the actual hook_theme() implementation, correct? Not a theme hook you are defining in hook_theme(). If so, by default, all hooks must be in the .module file. Hooks are meant to be callable at any time, and only .module files are loaded by default on every page load. However you can tell Drupal that a hook is in a different file by implementing hook_hook_info():

```
function hook_hook_info()
{
   $hooks['theme'] = ['group' => 'theme'];

   return $hooks;
}
```

With this code, Drupal will look for the hook (the array key 'theme') in the file MODULENAME.GROUPNAME.inc. In this case your GROUPNAME is defined as 'theme' in hook_hook_info(), so Drupal will load MODULENAME.theme.inc, whenever hook_theme() is invoked.

Now, if you meant that you want to put a theme hook that you define inside hook_theme() in another file, then you need to declare the file for that theme hook:

```
function hook_theme()
{
  return array
  (
    'some_theme_key' => array
    (
      'variables' => array(),
      'file' => 'path/to/file.inc', // relative to module root
    ),
  );
}
```

In this case, when the system tries to load the theme some_theme_key, it will load the file [MODULEFOLDER]/path/to/file.inc.

Comment: Thanks Jaypan, I wasn't aware that all hooks must be in the .module file. I thought that my .inc file mentioned in the .info file would be loaded as well.

Comment: I think those files are only scanned for classes. I'm not entirely clear on that though. It was something that was initially introduced as a requirement for D7, but then that requirement was dropped before D7 was released. The functionality was retained, but it was never clear to me exactly what/how it worked.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the addition. Would a ```require_once``` at the begining of the *.module* file be considered wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong - if it works it works. But the method I showed will be more lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **[module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x)** in your custom_module.module to load your .inc file

Comment: You should use `require_once` instead, `module_load_include` is only for use inside functions when Drupal is bootstrapped

Comment: Totally right Clive . Jaypan answer is the normal way. It must be a cache matter, but Tim, you can try first if it works with module_load_include, if so, switch to Clive answer's for Best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the reference to your file subfile.inc into info-file of your module.

```
files[] = subfile.inc
```

Comment: `files` is for class autoloading, this won't have the desired effect